# kendo showing "," and "%" in labels

Tags: kendo-ui, label, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo and am displaying labels on a bar chart. Right now with the following code the labels display numbers as "25.4". I need the labels to show the percentage sign after the number and thought I can do this in the label template part somewhere in "template: " #= value#"", but adding % or '%' or "%" doesn't work. **How can I get a % to show up with the number on the label?**

seriesDefaults: {
                    type: "column",
                    labels: {
                        visible: true,
                        background: "transparent",
                        template: " #= value#"
                    }
                },

In another chart I need to do a similar thing but have the labels display as a number but with a comma in appropriate places. Does anybody know how to do that also? Ex. I need 32,123 instead of 32123.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `template` I would suggest using `format` (but, of course, you can get the same thing using template).

Examples:

Printing `25.4` as `25.4%` would be

```
        seriesDefaults: {
          type: "column",
          labels: { 
            visible: true, 
            background: "transparent",
            format : "{0:n}%"
          }
        },
```

You can even make it display certain number of decimal digits using, for `3` use `format : "{0:n3}%"`:

```
        seriesDefaults: {
          type: "column",
          labels: { 
            visible: true, 
            background: "transparent",
            format : "{0:n3}%"
          }
        },
```

This is when you have the number stored as percentage, i.e. having `25%` stored as `25` and not as `0.25`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
    title: {
      text: "Total Sales (percentage)"
    },
    legend: {
      visible: false
    },
    seriesDefaults: {
      type: "column",
      labels: { 
        visible: true, 
        background: "transparent",
        format : "{0:n2}%"
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: "Serie1",
        data: [10, 20, 25, 30, 10, 5]
      }
    ],
    valueAxis: {
      max: 50,
      line: {
        visible: false
      },
      minorGridLines: {
        visible: true
      }
    },
    categoryAxis: {
      categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun"],
      majorGridLines: {
        visible: false
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1119/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart" style="height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thanks. Do you know how I could add commas in numbers that are displayed?

Comment: perfect, thanks. Do you know how I could add commas in numbers that are displayed? Here is my script. I'm trying to add commas on the 4 digit numbers in the data part so that when it displays it is "1,592" instead of "1592"                      
seriesDefaults:{
   type: "column",
   labels: {
   visible: true,
   background: "transparent",
   template: " $#= value#"
}
},
series: [{
  name: "Current",
  data: [1592, 3049, 1488, 1287, 1419, 1119, 1641, 1656]
}, {
 name: "Last Year",
 data: [1729, 1564, 1337, 933, 1352, 1201, 1659, 1396]
}],
tooltip: {
template: "#= series.name #: $#= value #"

Comment: You might try defining `format` as `{0:###,###.00}%`. This prints a `,` for the thousand and will force to print to decimal digits. If you don't want to force decimal digits you might consider `{0:###,###.##}%` or even `{0:###,###}%`.